# mkmapview refresh mapview

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, polyline

im using mkmapview to show route between current location and a coordinate.
 im using polyline to show the route. i have added annotation to start and destination. im using the following api to get the in between coordinates.

[http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/51.22545,4.40730,[51.22,4.41,51.2,4.41],51.23,4.42/car.js](http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/51.22545,4.40730,%5B51.22,4.41,51.2,4.41%5D,51.23,4.42/car.js)

now if i change the coordinates the already existing route also is visible. how do i remove the existing route and add a  new route? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something in your question, if you already have the app calculating and displaying an `MKPolyline` then all you need to do is remove the old one and add the new one. Your code would look something like

```
// generating new data, do this however you like
MKPolyline *routeLine = [self generateNewRoutLine];
MyPinAnnotation *startPin = [self generateNewStartPin];
MyPinAnnotation *endPin = [self generateNewEndPin];

// removing old overlays and adding new
[myMapView removeOverlays:myMapView.overlays]; // removes all overlays
[myMapView removeAnnotations:myMapView.annotations]; // removes all pins
[myMapView addOverlay:routeLine];
[myMapView addAnnotations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:startPin, endPin, nil]];
```